# Update views when an element of observable array changes

Tags: knockout.js

My view displays a list composed objects all stored in koObservableArray `MM.slideWellThumbnails`

The objects are displayed using `data-bind="foreach: slideWellThumbnails"`

I couldn't get an individual view of an object updated, when only one property (e.g. `confirmed` ) of an object was changed.

- I've tried to call: `MM.slideWellThumbnails.valueHasMutated();`
- I've declared the array with: `MM.slideWellThumbnails.extend({notify:
  'always'});`

It didn't help.

What I'm currently doing is, making a copy of the array, clearing the entire
array and then pushing the data back to the array. It works, but I guess it is not as the KO-inventor ment it.

```
MM.slideWellThumbnails()[ +well ].confirmed = confirmed;
MM.slideWellThumbnails1([]);

ko.utils.arrayForEach( MM.slideWellThumbnails(), function(data)
{
    MM.slideWellThumbnails1.push( data );
});
MM.slideWellThumbnails([]);
ko.utils.arrayForEach( MM.slideWellThumbnails1(), function(data)
{
    MM.slideWellThumbnails.push( data );
});
```

Is there an efficient way to do it?

Comment: It looks like `confirmed` itself is just a simple property, not a `ko.observable`?  The "correct" way to do it would be for it to be an observable that you can update the value of, without touching the array at all

Comment: I agree with @JamesThorpe.  Any property that you want to react to changes on will need to be an observable.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Ok, thanks for pointing me to this! Could fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to James Thorpe I could fix it:

Declared confirmed as observable:

```
var MyDataStructure= function( /*args*/ ) {
//...
this.confirmed = ko.observable(false)
//...
}
```

and assigned new value with:

```
//+well for explicitly converting to int from string
MM.slideWellThumbnails()[ +well ].confirmed(confirmed);
```

Thanks!